# var with nil value using protocol set get

Tags: swift, get, set, var

Why is the token `nil` after I set is value?

```
var token: Token {
    set {
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.token)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: File.UserDefaults.token)
    }
    get {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:  File.UserDefaults.token),
            let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Token {
            return obj
        } else {
            return Token()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `self.token` in the set statement use `newValue`.

```
set {
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: File.UserDefaults.token)
}
```

When calling self.token in set you are basically calling the get statement. To actually receive the value that is set you'll need to use `newValue`. newValue is basically a hidden parameter of the set statement.

Comment: It will save it to userDefaults, token can't have a value, it can only get and set. It's basically a getter and setter like in Java if you are familiar with that.